# Add calculated value from an array field to the same array

Tags: json, jq

Not sure if it is possible. I want multiply the "value" field with the "lvalue" field an put the result in a new field "calc" in the corresponding array entry.

Given JSON:

```
{
  "value": 5,
  "location": [{
    "city": "San Fracisco",
    "lvalue": 10
  },
  {
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "lvalue": 20
  }]
}
```

Expected Value in one JSON:

```
{
  "value": 5,
  "location": [{
    "city": "San Fracisco",
    "lvalue": 10,
    "calc": 50
  },
  {
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "lvalue": 20,
    "calc": 100
  }]
}
```

Comment: Sure it's possible. Straightforward, save the outer value in a variable, so you can reference it later when traversing the array: `jq '.value as $m | .location[] |= ( .calc = .lvalue * $m )'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to 'save' the `.value` in a variable before looping over the locations to update them using `|=`:

```
.value as $val | .location[] |= (.calc = $val * .lvalue)
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/cmbon4D0hTc)